# Torch Confusion matrix for binary criterion

Tags: machine-learning, torch, confusion-matrix

How do you use the optim packages' confusion matrix with the BCECriterion, which produces binary output? The last layer of my model is nn.logsigmoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusion matrix cannot accept 0s, it wants the class indices of the target and prediction.